# Not able to print anything in row 2 of confusion matrix

Tags: python, confusion-matrix

Can anyone please help!
I tried printing confusion matrix, but not able to get the values in row 2. I am not able to print anything in row 2 for the KNN Model trained.

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, classification_report, confusion_matrix

def plot_confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred):
    cm = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
    sns.heatmap(cm, annot=True, fmt="d", cmap="Blues")
    plt.xlabel("Predicted")
    plt.ylabel("Actual")
    plt.title("Confusion Matrix")
    plt.xticks([0, 1], ["Edible", "Poisonous"])
    plt.yticks([0, 1], ["Edible", "Poisonous"])
    plt.show()

target_names = ["Edible", "Poisonous"]

knn_classifier = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)
knn_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred = knn_classifier.predict(X_test)

print(classification_report(y_test, y_pred, target_names=target_names))

conf_matrix = confusion_matrix(y_test, y_pred)
plt.figure(figsize=(8, 6))
sns.heatmap(conf_matrix, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap='Blues', xticklabels=target_names, yticklabels=target_names)
plt.xlabel('Predicted')
plt.ylabel('Actual')
plt.title('Confusion Matrix')
plt.show()

accuracy = accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
print("Accuracy:", accuracy)```
````

Comment: You should add more info regarding what you mean by "not able to print". Report any error codes or behaviour in more detail. Have you tried print(conf_matrix). I know this is not what you are trying to do but would be help to debug your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you’re not importing the sns module for Seaborn visualization. Make sure you import it at the beginning of your script.

Add `import seaborn` as sns after your import statements. This should resolve the issue with not being able to print anything in row 2 for the KNN model.